# Converting C++ solution to a class library

Tags: c#, c++, class

this might be a simple question, but as I have zero experience in C++ and my boss has given me a C++ solution work with I need to ask this question.

I have a C++ solution that needs to be turned into a .NET class library which can then be used in another .NET solution done in C#.

Is this even possible???

Cheers

Comment: an *unmanaged* C++ solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap all C++ classes that should be visible in .NET in C++/CLI classes.

[Read this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/quickcppcli.aspx)

There are also some automated tools to do this, but I never used these (I don't really trust them). Depends on how many C++ classes do you have, and how complex they are. Writing the wrappers is mostly straight-forward once you get used to some oddities of C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the output of the C++ solution. Is it an application (*.exe) or a library (*.dll)?

If it is a library (*.dll) you can use [Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx) to call its functions out of managed code. A lot of examples of calling Win32 native functions can be found at http://pinvoke.net/.

If your result is an application it could be possible, that it has a COM interface. In that case you could use the [COM interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to communicate with your application.

Last but not least you could write with C++/CLI a managed wrapper around your C++ functionality. But this is a lot of work and has many pitfalls.